# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str (MAPNIK)

Tags: python, string, typeerror, mapnik

I am writing a function to calculate the shortest path to certain points along roads rather than as the crow flies, however i keep getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "P:\understandinggis\assessment2\Assessment2.py", line 177, in
>   
>       if shortestPath1(g, line) <= maxDist:   File "P:\understandinggis\assessment2\Assessment2.py", line 14, in
>   shortestPath1
>       azF,azB,distance = g.inv(line["coordinates"][l][0], line["coordinates"][l][1], lines["coordinates"][l+1][0],
>   line["coordinates"][l+1][1]) TypeError: list indices must be integers,
>   not str

here's the line of code it refers to:

```
def shortestPath1 (g, line):
        #initialise cumulativelength
        cumulativeLength = 0
        for l in range(len(line)-1):
                azF,azB,distance = g.inv(line['coordinates'][l][0], line['coordinates'][l][1], lines['coordinates'][l+1][0], line['coordinates'][l+1][1])
                cumulativeLength += distance
                return cumulativeLength
```

Comment: You can't do `line['coordinates']`. Unless it's a dictionary, but the system is letting you know that it's a list, so you must do something like `line[3]`. What you put in the `[]` must be a integer (number), or a variable pointing to an integer. Maybe post what you expect `line` to be, so we can help you access it. Do you define a variable called `coordinates` anywhere? If so, please post that as well.

Comment: Please include an example (see link below) so that other users can help you better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve